Scripting in the QGIS console crash during iteration pandas dataframe groupby or get_group
The code (dated 28.05.2024) worked correctly every week in QGIS console until 06.08.2024, after begins to crash every week. QGIS version was updated from 3.28 to 3.34, but in September. The problem comes in August. No errors are shown.
#three geoservices that determine a cascade that allows to build different files targeting tha municipalities 
#in a directory showing the protected zones that still have to be managed by public autority 
#this geoservices are the bases for the work, if they changed uri or field name the cascade could be affected
#it would be necessary to cheek periodically what is produced
#the cascede run every 7 days with the aid of task scheduler that initiate "launch.bat"
#for every municipalities the cascade allow to build a vector gpkg, an excel (attribute table of gpgk) and a pdf (atlas)

#the geoservice are called, zp (stay for "protected zone) is intranet, the oter two geoservices are public
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import urllib

# from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()


base_url_wfs_intranet = "xxxxx"
params_registry = {
    "MAP": "/project/wfs_ac.qgz",
    "pagingEnabled": "true",
    "restrictToRequestBBOX": "1",
    "srsname": "EPSG:2056",
    "typename": "ac_001_1_v1_1_disponibilita_catasto_rdpp",
    "version": "auto",
    }
uri_registry = base_url_wfs_intranet + urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlencode(params_registry))
registry = QgsVectorLayer(
    uri_registry,
    "ac_001_1_v1_1_disponibilita_catasto_rdpp",
    "WFS",
    )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(registry)

base_url_wfs_oasi = "xxxxxx"
params_zp = {
    "pageSize": "0",
    "pagingEnabled": "true",
    "restrictToRequestBBOX": "1",
    "srsname": "EPSG:2056",
    "typename": "ch.ti.oasi.maps.areeprotezione.zone",
    "version": '1.1.0',
    }
uri_zp = base_url_wfs_oasi + urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlencode(params_zp))
zp = QgsVectorLayer(
    uri_zp,
    "ch.ti.oasi.maps.areeprotezione.zone",
    "WFS",
    )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(zp)

base_url_wfs_intranet = "xxxxx"
params_municipalities = {
    "MAP": "/project/wfs_ac.qgz",
    "pagingEnabled": "true",
    "restrictToRequestBBOX": "1",
    "srsname": "EPSG:2056",
    "typename": "ac_002_1_v1_1_limiti_giurisdizionali_indicativi_comuni",
    "version": "auto",
    }
uri_municipalities = base_url_wfs_intranet + urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlencode(params_municipalities))
municipalities = QgsVectorLayer(
    uri_municipalities,
    "ac_002_1_v1_1_limiti_giurisdizionali_indicativi_comuni",
    "WFS",
    )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(municipalities)
#current working directory is setted to work with relative path.
import os
from pathlib import Path

#is the current working directory
directory_projectqgs = Path.cwd()

#zone_selected_municipalities is created. it contains the zones that still have to be managed by public autority. 
#this vector will be merged with another. This first vector represents not approved zones that are within the boundary of municipalities
#that has the attribute d_ch_131" = 'true
zone_municipalities = processing.run("native:intersection",{'INPUT': uri_zp,
    'OVERLAY': uri_municipalities,
    'INPUT_FIELDS':['OID','OSSERVAZIONI','CLASSE','STATO','ID_REGOLAMENTO_FK','ID_RISOLUZIONE_FK','SCALA_FONTE','ANNO_FONTE','TIPO_FONTE','AUTORE_STUDIO','VALIDAZIONE_STATO','VALIDAZIONE_DT_IST','VALIDAZIONE_DT_UPA','VALIDAZIONE_NOTE','PROPRIETARIO','GESTORE','CATALOGAZIONE_IST','CATALOGAZIONE_UPAAI','RAPPORTO_IDROGEOLOGICO','PREAVVISO_IST','PREAVVISO_UPAAI_1','CATASTO_AI','PIANO_RG','PREAVVISO_UPAAI_2','APPROVAZIONE_MUN','APPROVAZIONE_UPAAI','NOTIFIFICA_AI_PROPRIETARI','ESAME_RICORSI','AUTORITA','ADAT_PART','OASIVERSION'],
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS':['comune_min'],
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX':'',
    'OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'./zone_comuni.gpkg\' table=\"zone_comuni\" (geom)'})
zone_municipalities = QgsVectorLayer(
    "./zone_comuni.gpkg",
    "zone_comuni",
    "ogr"
    )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(zone_municipalities)

processing.run ("qgis:selectbyexpression",{'INPUT': uri_registry,
    'EXPRESSION':'\"d_ch_131\" = \'true\'',
    'METHOD':0})

processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT': zone_municipalities,
    'PREDICATE':[0],
    'INTERSECT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(uri_registry, selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),
    'METHOD':0})
    
processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {'INPUT': zone_municipalities,
    'EXPRESSION':' \"VALIDAZIONE_STATO\" = \'non validato\' OR  \"VALIDAZIONE_STATO\" = \'richiesta verifica da UPAAI\' OR \"VALIDAZIONE_STATO\" = \'validato IST\' ',
    'METHOD':3})
    
zone_selected_municipalities = processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT': zone_municipalities,
    'OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'./zone_comuni_selezionati.gpkg\' table=\"zone_comuni_selezionati\" (geom)'})
zone_selected_municipalities = QgsVectorLayer(
    "./zone_comuni_selezionati.gpkg",
    "zone_comuni_selezionati",
    "ogr"
    )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(zone_selected_municipalities)

#the second vector to be merged is created. It contains approved zones with hydrological research older than 2004 
#that are within the boundary of municipalities and that has the attribute d_ch_131" = 'true
zone_municipalities2 = processing.run("native:intersection",
    {'INPUT': uri_zp,
    'OVERLAY': uri_municipalities,
    'INPUT_FIELDS':['OID','OSSERVAZIONI','CLASSE','STATO','ID_REGOLAMENTO_FK','ID_RISOLUZIONE_FK','SCALA_FONTE','ANNO_FONTE','TIPO_FONTE','AUTORE_STUDIO','VALIDAZIONE_STATO','VALIDAZIONE_DT_IST','VALIDAZIONE_DT_UPA','VALIDAZIONE_NOTE','PROPRIETARIO','GESTORE','CATALOGAZIONE_IST','CATALOGAZIONE_UPAAI','RAPPORTO_IDROGEOLOGICO','PREAVVISO_IST','PREAVVISO_UPAAI_1','CATASTO_AI','PIANO_RG','PREAVVISO_UPAAI_2','APPROVAZIONE_MUN','APPROVAZIONE_UPAAI','NOTIFIFICA_AI_PROPRIETARI','ESAME_RICORSI','AUTORITA','ADAT_PART','OASIVERSION'],
    'OVERLAY_FIELDS':['comune_min'],'OVERLAY_FIELDS_PREFIX':'',
    'OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'./zone_comuni2.gpkg\' table=\"zone_comuni\" (geom)'})    
zone_municipalities2 = QgsVectorLayer("./zone_comuni2.gpkg","zone_comuni2", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(zone_municipalities2)

processing.run ("qgis:selectbyexpression", {'INPUT': uri_registry,
    'EXPRESSION':'\"d_ch_131\" = \'true\'',
    'METHOD':0})
    
processing.run("native:selectbylocation", {'INPUT': zone_municipalities2,
    'PREDICATE':[0],
    'INTERSECT':QgsProcessingFeatureSourceDefinition(uri_registry, selectedFeaturesOnly=True, featureLimit=-1, geometryCheck=QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryAbortOnInvalid),
    'METHOD':0})
    
processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {'INPUT': zone_municipalities2,
    'EXPRESSION':' \"VALIDAZIONE_STATO\" = \'validato UPAAI\' AND \"ANNO_FONTE\" < 2004 ',
    'METHOD':3})
    
processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT': zone_municipalities2,
    'OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'./zone_comuni2_selezionati.gpkg\' table=\"zone_comuni2_selezionati\" (geom)'})
zone_selected_municipalities2 = QgsVectorLayer(
    "./zone_comuni2_selezionati.gpkg",
    "zone_comuni2_selezionati",
    "ogr"
    )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(zone_selected_municipalities2)

#zone_selected_municipalities and zone_selected_municipalities2 are merged
merged_zone = processing.run("native:mergevectorlayers",
    {'LAYERS':[zone_selected_municipalities, zone_selected_municipalities2],
    'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:2056'),
    'OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'./zone_fuse.gpkg\' table=\"zone_fuse\" (geom)'})
merged_zone = QgsVectorLayer("./zone_fuse.gpkg",
    "zone_fuse",
    "ogr"
    )

#new field in merged_zone that allows processing.run of native:splitvectorlayer later, in fact the field "comune_min" merged_zone
#cannot be executed with native:splitvectorlayer because of "/" in some attributes. The new field is called "comune_min_corr" 
#and is deprived from "/"
#even "-" is replaced with " " because gives problem if we wanted to split the report
with edit(merged_zone):
    for feature in merged_zone.getFeatures():
        new_value = feature['comune_min'].replace('/', ' ')
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('comune_min'), new_value)
        new_value = feature['comune_min'].replace('-', ' ')
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('comune_min'), new_value)
        new_value = feature['comune_min'].replace("'", " ")
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('comune_min'), new_value)
        merged_zone.updateFeature(feature)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_zone)

#merged_zone is used to create two big excels. One is for cantonal public autority, the other is for comunal public
#autority
import pandas as pd
#create a list f the name of the fields and create the feature
cols = [f.name() for f in merged_zone.fields()] 
datagen = ([f[col] for col in cols] for f in merged_zone.getFeatures())
#dataframe is created and the field comune_min is sorted ascending following alphabetical order
df_merged_zone = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=datagen, columns=cols)
df_merged_zone = df_merged_zone.sort_values(by=['comune_min'])
#index=false means that index at links is not created, there is also possibility #header=false to delete name field at the top
#the first excel is created
xls_merged_zone = df_merged_zone.to_excel('./zone_fuse.xlsx', index=False)
#second excel is created simply deleting some fields
df_merged_zone_send = df_merged_zone.drop(['OSSERVAZIONI', 'VALIDAZIONE_NOTE', 'path', 'layer'], axis=1)
xls_merged_zone_send = df_merged_zone_send.to_excel('./zone_fuse_privacy.xlsx',index=False)

#the vector for the municipalities is created by deleting some fields, later it will be splitted with the algorithm native:splitvectorlayer
merged_zone_send = processing.run("qgis:deletecolumn",
{'INPUT': merged_zone,
'COLUMN':['OSSERVAZIONI','VALIDAZIONE_NOTE','layer','path'],
'OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'./zone_fuse_privacy.gpkg\' table=\"zone_fuse_privacy\" (geom)'})
merged_zone_send = QgsVectorLayer(
    "./zone_fuse_privacy.gpkg",
    "zone_fuse_privacy",
    "ogr"
    )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_zone_send)

#it is assumed that if there are errors the code stops before this step, then if 
#the code arrive here it would be able to end the code creating all the files for the 
#municipalities. To simplify the management of the files the following code delete 
#all the file inside the directory "Spedire" that contain all the result before 
#begin to create the new one. 
from pathlib import Path
p=Path('Comuni')
for stem in p.iterdir(): 
    stem.with_suffix('.gpkg').unlink(missing_ok=True)
    stem.with_suffix('.xlsx').unlink(missing_ok=True)
    stem.with_suffix('.pdf').unlink(missing_ok=True)

#the vector for the municipalities is created, the algorithm split merged_zone_send in many vectors, as many as 
#there are the municipalities involved. The content of every new created vector is a subset of the vector
#merged_zone_send. The subset is created based on the attribute of comune_min
processing.run("native:splitvectorlayer",
    {'INPUT': merged_zone_send,
    'FIELD':'comune_min',
    'FILE_TYPE':0,
    'OUTPUT':'./Comuni'})
    
#create an array with the unique values of the field comune_min of the merged_zone_send
cols = ['comune_min'] 
datagen = ([f[col] for col in cols] for f in merged_zone_send.getFeatures())
df_merged_zone_send_comune_min = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=datagen, columns=cols)
#create an array with unique values frome the dataframe
array_merged_zone_send = df_merged_zone_send_comune_min['comune_min'].unique()

#the "native:splitvectorlayer" creates many gpgk with the prefix comune_min, prefix is based on the field used to create gpkg
#and it cannot be setted when the algorithm is executed. 
#the iteration changes the prefix from comune_min to zp. If files with zp prefix were already in the directory, 
#it would overwrite the older file with the new builded zp files
for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
    variable = Path('Comuni')/f'comune_min_{municipality}.gpkg'
    variable.replace(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}_privacy.gpkg')
    
#create many excels from the xls_merged_zone_send based on the array with unique values and using the field comune_min
#of the dataframe df_merged_zone_send 
for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
    grouped = df_merged_zone_send.groupby(['comune_min'])
    xls_merged_zone_send = grouped.get_group(municipality)
    xls_merged_zone_send.to_excel(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}_privacy.xlsx',index=False)
    
#the vector for the municipalities is created, the algorithm split merged_zone in many vectors, as many as 
#there are the municipalities involved. The content of every new created vector is a subset of the vector
#merged_zone. The subset is created based on the attribute of comune_min. 
#The number of new gpkg have to be the same of when it was created with the split of the merged_zone_send. 
#The difference between the two split is that here there are some additional fields in the vector. 
processing.run("native:splitvectorlayer",
    {'INPUT': merged_zone,
    'FIELD':'comune_min',
    'FILE_TYPE':0,
    'OUTPUT':'./Comuni'})

#the "native:splitvectorlayer" creates many gpgk with the prefix comune_min, prefix is based on the field used to create gpkg
#and it cannot be setted when the algorithm is executed. 
#the iteration changes the prefix from comune_min to zp. If files with zp prefix were already in the directory, 
#it would overwrite the older file with the new builded zp files.
#to be noted: is used the already created array_merged_zone_send based on the merged_zone_send
#because the features of vector merged_zone_send are identical tos merged_zone
for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
    variable = Path('Comuni')/f'comune_min_{municipality}.gpkg'
    variable.replace(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}.gpkg')

#create many excels from the xls_merged_zone based on the array with unique values and using the field comune_min
#of the dataframe df_merged_zone.
#to be noted: is used the already created array_merged_zone_send based on the merged_zone_send
#because the features of vector merged_zone_send are identical tos merged_zone
for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
    grouped = df_merged_zone.groupby(['comune_min'])
    xls_merged_zone = grouped.get_group(municipality)
    xls_merged_zone.to_excel(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}.xlsx',index=False)

#the new created files 'f'zp_{municipality}.xlsx' that are in folder ('Comuni') are modified. 
#An additional column with a fill color yellow is added
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.cell import Cell

for file in os.listdir(Path('Comuni')):
    for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
        if file.startswith(f'zp_{municipality}.xlsx'):
            wb = load_workbook(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}.xlsx')
            ws=wb["Sheet1"]
            for col in ws.iter_cols(min_col=ws.max_column+1, min_row=0, max_col=ws.max_column+1, max_row=ws.max_row):
                for cell in col:
                    yellowFill = PatternFill(start_color='00FFFF00',
                               end_color='00FFFF00',
                               fill_type='solid')
                    cell.fill = yellowFill
            ws.cell(row=1, column=ws.max_column).value = 'Compilare'
            ws.cell(row=1, column=ws.max_column).font = Font(name='Calibri', size=11, bold=True)
            xls_merged_zone_edited = wb.save(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}.xlsx')

#create a vector from geoservice municipalities that allows the construction of the vector filtered
#for the atlas. 
option = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
option.driverName = "GPKG"
municipalities_exp = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2 (municipalities, "./ac_002_1_v1_1_limiti_giurisdizionali_indicativi_comuni", QgsCoordinateTransformContext(), option)
municipalities_exp = QgsVectorLayer(
    "./ac_002_1_v1_1_limiti_giurisdizionali_indicativi_comuni.gpkg",
    "ac_002_1_v1_1_limiti_giurisdizionali_indicativi_comuni_exp",
    "ogr"
    )
#field "comune_min" in municipalities_exp is adapted to the other "comune_min" in the other vectors
#it allows comparison of this vector with the others
with edit(municipalities_exp):
    for feature in municipalities_exp.getFeatures():
        new_value = feature['comune_min'].replace('/', ' ')
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('comune_min'), new_value)
        new_value = feature['comune_min'].replace('-', ' ')
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('comune_min'), new_value)
        new_value = feature['comune_min'].replace("'", " ")
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('comune_min'), new_value)
        municipalities_exp.updateFeature(feature)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(municipalities_exp)

#allow to select the feature in municipalities_exp that have the same attribute in field "comune_min" of 
#the vector merged_zone. 
field1 = 'comune_min'
field2 = 'comune_min'
merged_zone.selectAll()
selected_features = [feat[field1] for feat in merged_zone.selectedFeatures()]
selected_attributes = f'({selected_features[0]})' if len(selected_features) == 1 else tuple(selected_features)
expression = f'"{field2}" in {selected_attributes}'
municipalities_exp.selectByExpression(expression)

#selected features in municipalities_exp are exported and is created a new vector
#the vector shows the municipality where there are features in merged_zone.
#features in merged_zone are the protected zones that still have to be managed by public autority
#then, the new vector is the vector of the municipality that is filtered and only contains
#municipalities that have zones insides
municipalities_exp_filtered = processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures",
    {'INPUT': municipalities_exp,
    'OUTPUT':'ogr:dbname=\'./comuni_filtrati.gpkg\' table=\"comuni_filtrati\" (geom)'})
municipalities_exp_filtered = QgsVectorLayer(
    "./comuni_filtrati.gpkg",
    "comuni_filtrati",
    "ogr"
    )
#all layer are removed and is necessary to build the view that the allow the atlas to show what we want
QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers()

#create an instance for the standalone script. We want avoid making too much modification, so 
#atleast the core script we try to make equal to standalone. The next 4 lines allows to avoid writing 
#QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(geoadmin), QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_zone) and 
#QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(municipalities_exp_filtered) as done before, the vector are added automatically
#after "QgsRasterLayer" and "QgsRasterLayer"
project_path = os.getcwd() + '/crdpp.qgz'
project_instance = QgsProject.instance()
project_instance.read(project_path)

#add the geoservice WMS as basemap 
params_geoadmin = {
    "contextualWMSLegend":"0",
    "crs": "EPSG:2056",
    "dpiMode": "7",
    "featureCount": "10",
    "format": "image/jpeg",
    "layers": "ch.swisstopo.landeskarte-grau-10",
    "styles&url": "https://wms.geo.admin.ch/"
    }
uri_geoadmin = urllib.parse.unquote(urllib.parse.urlencode(params_geoadmin))
geoadmin = QgsRasterLayer(
    uri_geoadmin,
    "ch.swisstopo.landeskarte-grau-10",
    "wms",
    )
#    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(geoadmin)

#vector of the zones (merged_zones_send) and of municipalities_exp_filtered are added
merged_zone = QgsVectorLayer(
    "./zone_fuse.gpkg",
    "zone_fuse",
    "ogr"
    )
#set of a rule based symbology adapted to the atlas for merged_zone 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
symbol = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(merged_zone.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
def add_rule_to_renderer(label, expression, color):
    rule = renderer.rootRule().children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol().setColor(QColor(color))
    renderer.rootRule().appendChild(rule)
#to pay attention to not simply copy the expression from QGIS, but to add '\' for the attribute, otherwise it 
#does not work
add_rule_to_renderer ('S1', '"CLASSE" = \'S1\' and intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry)','#bed2ff')
add_rule_to_renderer('S2', '"CLASSE" = \'S2\' and intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry)','#bee8ff')
add_rule_to_renderer ('S3', '"CLASSE" = \'S3\' and intersects($geometry, @atlas_geometry)','#beffe8')
#remove the default symbol (it would be the forth) 
renderer.rootRule().removeChildAt(0)
merged_zone.setRenderer(renderer)
merged_zone.triggerRepaint()

#    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(merged_zone)

#set symbology adapted to the atlas for municipalities_exp_filtered
symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color':'#289e26',
                                    'color_border':'#e31a1c',
                                    'width_border':'1.06',
                                    'style':'no'})
#symbology added to a rule based renderer for the atlas
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer(symbol)
#the function that added expression and label to the rule renderer 
def add_rule_to_renderer(label, expression):
    rule = renderer.rootRule().children()[0].clone()
    rule.setLabel(label)
    rule.setFilterExpression(expression)
    rule.symbol()
    renderer.rootRule().appendChild(rule)
#the parameter label and the rule expression are added to renderer based on the function
add_rule_to_renderer ('limite comunale', '$id=@atlas_featureid')
#remove the default symbol (it would be the forth) 
renderer.rootRule().removeChildAt(0)
#renderer is setted for merged_exp_filtered
municipalities_exp_filtered.setRenderer(renderer)
municipalities_exp_filtered.triggerRepaint()

#    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(municipalities_exp_filtered)

#Atlas is created and creates many files zp_nomecomune.pdf. Very important is to set filter expression and output
#as in this code. The atlas is called atlas and is in this project. As for the styles official_style_zone_fuse.qml and official_style_comuni_filtrati.qml, the atlas has 
#not been created with pyqgis. If the project crdpp is deleted, even the standalone version won't be able
#to run the atlas.
for feature in municipalities_exp_filtered.getFeatures():
    parameters = {'LAYOUT':'atlas',
    'COVERAGE_LAYER': municipalities_exp_filtered,
    'FILTER_EXPRESSION':"comune_min ='{}'".format(feature['comune_min']),
    'SORTBY_EXPRESSION':'',
    'SORTBY_REVERSE':False,
    'OUTPUT':'./Comuni/zp_{}.pdf'.format(feature['comune_min']),
    'LAYERS':None,
    'DPI':None,
    'FORCE_VECTOR':False,
    'GEOREFERENCE':True,
    'INCLUDE_METADATA':True,
    'DISABLE_TILED':False,
    'SIMPLIFY':True,
    'TEXT_FORMAT':0}
    out = processing.run("native:atlaslayouttopdf", parameters)

QgsProject.instance().removeAllMapLayers()

The first crash occurs with (line 237):
for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
    grouped = df_merged_zone_send.groupby(['comune_min'])
    xls_merged_zone_send = grouped.get_group(municipality)
    xls_merged_zone_send.to_excel(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}_privacy.xlsx',index=False)

The crash does not occur if some lines before I replace the following code:
cols = ['comune_min'] 
datagen = ([f[col] for col in cols] for f in merged_zone_send.getFeatures())
df_merged_zone_send_comune_min = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=datagen, columns=cols)
#create an array with unique values frome the dataframe
array_merged_zone_send = df_merged_zone_send_comune_min['comune_min'].unique()

With that:
#create an array with the unique values of the field comune_min of the merged_zone_send
df_merged_zone_send = pd.read_excel('./zone_fuse_privacy.xlsx')
#create an array with unique values frome the dataframe
array_merged_zone_send = df_merged_zone_send['comune_min'].unique()

Unfortunately after the correction QGIS (line 267) will crash again here:
for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
    grouped = df_merged_zone.groupby(['comune_min'])
    xls_merged_zone = grouped.get_group(municipality)
    xls_merged_zone.to_excel(Path('Comuni')/f'zp_{municipality}.xlsx',index=False)

and for that I have no solution. Even the standalone script gives the same error (I know because it stops to create xlsx at the same point!). Hovewer, It gives me message only deprecation warning for future versions, but no message with error.

If the issue started to occur when you hadn't updated QGIS yet and you hadn't updated any Python module and library used by the script, then you need to check what changed in the data that leads to the crash.
